# Is soap forming micelles in water an exothermic reaction?

Tags: water

I have seen it described as soap molecules releasing energy when forming micelles. Is that correct? Is it an exothermic reaction?

I mean a bunch of molecules uniting to form a micelle.

Comment: Reserve "reaction" to process involving a change in chemical nature of the species involved (change of the primary structure, to extend the terminology used in protein and bio- chemistry to material science and supramolecular chemistry. If we want, micelles formation is an example).

Comment: This overlaps to other questions written by you. From those thread you should already knew it, isn't?

Comment: Endothermic process but governed by entropic changes of the water, see the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micelle